# Resizable MovieClip Component?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I was wondering if any one can be kind and help me, I was looking on google about a class or component in as3 that allow me to load an assets like a swf or image an give me so sort of handlers to change the size of the asset loaded, you know like in flash when you want change the size of a symbol you have a little squares handlers that you can pull to change the size, I don't want to reinvented the wheel, and I'm sure it should a be a class or component that I get or buy, it just I haven't any luck searching, thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look [here](http://www.quietless.com/kitchen/transform-tool-drag-scale-and-rotate-at-runtime/) for an example with sources file or another one [here](http://www.senocular.com/demo/TransformToolAS3/TransformTool.html)

Comment: +1 Although the first example is a bit broken on my browser... second one works much better.